# android help needed in the code

Tags: android, android-layout

i want to read the text from the file in raw directory(rules.txt) file and display its text into the help activity
there isn't any error in the code but when i run it in the emulator the app crashes.
can anyone sort this out.. i am new developer in android

```
public class HelpActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.help);
    InputStream iFile = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.rules);
    TextView helpText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView_HelpText);
    String strFile = inputStreamToString(iFile);
    helpText.setText(strFile);
}

private String inputStreamToString(InputStream iFile) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
 }
}
```

Comment: where is the implementation for inputStreamToString() method? What code inside it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should use something like this:

```
public static String getDataFromResources(Context context, int resID) throws IOException {
    InputStream iStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(resID);
    Writer writer = new StringWriter();
    char[] buffer = new char[1024];
    try {
        Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream, "UTF-8"));
        int n;
        while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
        }
    } finally {
        iStream.close();
    }
    return writer.toString();
}
```